# error NG8004: No pipe found with name 'name' error after migrating from angular 9 to angular 16

Tags: angular, typescript, server, migration

src/app/views/viewbill/viewbill.component.html:27:48 - error NG8004: No pipe found with name 'number'.

27                         TOTAL : {{item.total | number:'.3'}}                                                here i am facing error like this but in angular 15 and type script version 4  it works, coming to angular 16 it shows error like this.can any one can help me to solve this error.

i tried deleting packagelock.json and node modules and run npm install --force. but the same error occur for many  files.also i changed typescript versions as well

Comment: are you importing CommonModule to the right place?

Comment: Yes i iported to right place

Comment: most likely you are not. number pipe is a part of CommonModule (or BrowserModule if we are talking about the root module). you should import it in the component imports if the component is standalone, or to the corresponding module where the component is defined

Comment: can you please tell me in detail

Comment: imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
   
  ], i imported common modules in myapp.module.ts

Comment: where is viewbill component declared? Common module should be provided there as well

Comment: it is declared in viewbill component.ts.alsocommon module is declared there

Comment: shows these much errors after running ng serve                                                                     Error: src/app/views/view-return-bill/view-return-bill.component.html:33:67 - error NG8004: No pipe found with name 'number'.

33                     <b>{{grandTax.key}} : </b> {{grandTax.value | number:'.3'}}
                                                                     ~~~~~~